# Trouble installing `pip` on windows

Tags: python, installation, pip

I'm trying to install `pip` in windows. I followed the instruction from [this website](https://www.liquidweb.com/kb/install-pip-windows/) :

- first I `cd` the directory where `get-pip.py` resides and then wrote `get-pip.py`. I then get a message `collecting pip` and then get this message again and again `connection to pypi.org timed out`

However I get this message:

[image]

Comment: What python version do you have? Pip should be bundled with python. What output do you get after `python -m pip  --version`?

Comment: Also use `python get-pip.py` instead of `get-pip.py`.

Comment: Many thanks @needtobe. Indeed you are right: I get `pip 18.1` after typing `python -m pip --version`. The if you want to install let's say pandas you type `python -m pip install pandas` correct?

Comment: well actually no, when I type `python -m pip install pandas`, I get  `Connection to pypi.org timed out`

Comment: Try `pip --default-timeout=1000 install pandas`, but I would highly recommend using virtual environments instead.

Comment: So when typing `python -m pip --default-timeout=1000 install pandas`, I get the same error message `Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond`

Comment: Try disabling antivirus. Do you use proxy?

Comment: yes I think, I ll need to try that at home though. Many thanks for the feedback